# Implement Path Navigation bar (Breadcrumb bar) control

Tags: javafx, navigationbar, breadcrumbs

I want to generate an UI where someone can navigate through the path of a tree structure. Here is an example of what I want, taken from JavaFX Scene Builder.

Depending on the actual position in an TreeView, this UI is updated. By clicking on individual items the tree is updated.

[image]

My question:
What Nodes/Controls are best used for this approach? (no full code required. Just mention the name of the controls).

My first idea is to generate a row of buttons closely to each other, but maybe there are better ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably too broad, simply because there are so many different ways you could do this. I assume you mean `TreeView`, not `TableView` here? I would probably try with `ToggleButton`s in a single `ToggleGroup`. You can register a listener with the `ToggleGroup`'s `selectedToggleProperty` to update the selection in the tree, and register a listener with the tree's selection model to select a particular `ToggleButton`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, i meant `TreeView`. I'll have a look at `ToggleButton`.

Comment: Have a look at JavaFX ESSEMBLES online .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ControlsFx](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx)'s [BreadCrumbBar](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/BreadCrumbBar.html)

[image]

```
Pane root = ...
Label selectedCrumbLbl = new Label();

BreadCrumbBar<String> sampleBreadCrumbBar = new BreadCrumbBar<>();
root.getChildren().addAll(sampleBreadCrumbBar, selectedCrumbLbl);

TreeItem<String> model = BreadCrumbBar.buildTreeModel("Hello", "World", "This", "is", "cool");
sampleBreadCrumbBar.setSelectedCrumb(model);

sampleBreadCrumbBar.setOnCrumbAction(new EventHandler<BreadCrumbBar.BreadCrumbActionEvent<String>>() {
        @Override public void handle(BreadCrumbActionEvent<String> bae) {
            selectedCrumbLbl.setText("You just clicked on '" + bae.getSelectedCrumb() + "'!");
        }
});
```

https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx-samples/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/samples/button/HelloBreadCrumbBar.java

Answer (score 1):

The chosen solution did not work for me. I had to listen to the `selectedCrumbProperty`.

```
TreeItem<String> helloView = new TreeItem("Hello");
TreeItem<String> worldView = new TreeItem("World");
hellowView.getChildren().add(worldView);
TreeItem<String> thisView = new TreeItem("This");
worldView.getChildren().add(thisView);
TreeItem<String> isView = new TreeItem("is");
thisView.getChildren().add(isView);
BreadCrumbBar<String> sampleBreadCrumbBar = new BreadCrumbBar<>(helloView);
sampleBreadCrumbBar.setSelectedCrumb(helloView);

sampleBreadCrumbBar.selectedCrumbProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
    System.out.println(newValue);
    if (newValue == worldView) {
        //load this view
    }
});
```

I typed this directly into the answer. There may be errors. Leave a note.